# ADO recordset getstring slow for large recordsets

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, adodb

I'm using ADO in VBScript. The query is simple and completes in a couple of seconds.

However, when I execute the GetString method, it takes a very long time to complete and sometimes never completes at all.

```
Set oShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )

user = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%UserName%")

ConnectSqlServer "select top 100000 * from notices FOR JSON AUTO, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES;", "PSQL003"

Sub ConnectSqlServer(query, database)
    On Error Resume Next
    sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source= " & database & "; " & _
                  "Initial Catalog=VIEW;" & _
                  "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    MakeConnectionString = "DSN=" & sDSN & ";Uid=" & sUid & ";Pwd=" & sPwd & ";"

    Dim conn
    Dim rs
    Dim sConnString
    Dim resultString
    
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    
    conn.Open sConnString
    conn.CommandTimeout = 0
    Set rs = conn.Execute(query)
    Set Errs1 = conn.Errors
    For Each errLoop In Errs1
          With errLoop
            StrTmp = StrTmp & "Error #" & i & ":"
            StrTmp = StrTmp & vbCrLf & "   ADO Error   #" & .Number
            StrTmp = StrTmp & vbCrLf & "   Description  " & .Description
            StrTmp = StrTmp & vbCrLf & "   Source       " & .Source
            i = i + 1
       End With
    Next

    Msgbox "Query Finished"

    resultString = rs.GetString

    Msgbox "String Created"
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use `GetString()` for large recordsets for this very reason. What do you expect when you are trying to format 100000 results as JSON?

Comment: @Lankymart What is the better alternative?

Comment: What is it you are trying to do with 100000 rows worth of JSON formatted output?

Comment: I’m creating a tool for reporting, and for security reasons I must use this script. It writes the JSON to a file which I then parse in a different system. Users can execute queries that return 10 rows or even 100,000.

Comment: For what it is worth: returning as rows still has the issue

Comment: Then I suggest you page the recordset rather than trying to return 100000 records in one JSON object.